# locating images on a for loop, and then adding an event?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, titanium, addeventlistener

i have this scenario where im loading images using a for loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {

 var likeImage= Titanium.UI.createImageView({
    image:'like.png',
    width:17,
    height:10,
    left:110,
    top:4
});

}
```

then im adding an event, if the one of the hearts is clicked it should change image.

```
likeImage.addEventListener("click", function(e) {

likeImage.image = 'unlike.jpg';

});
```

but when i click nothing is happening, can anyone shed light on this problem please, thanks guys

edit:

```
 tableView.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
var tappedRow = e.row;


                    alert(tappedRow.username1.text);

                });
```

but its giving me an erro, saying this is not an object! or unidentified!! thanks

Comment: extra info: the heart is like.png

Comment: you are going to need to include more code for som real help here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use 'this' instead of likeImage:

```
likeImage.addEventListener("click", function(e) {

    this.image = 'unlike.jpg';

});
```

Answer (score 2):

EDIT --

After looking at all the code,

http://paste.bradleygill.com/index.php?paste_id=152785

you dont need to put a click event on the image, put the click event on the tableView and the "event.source" will be the object that received the click.

if the object that received the click is one of your "likeImages" then change it to unlike or whatever else you want to do

Comment: hey aaron thanks, this is the full code, i dont know why its not working, thanks for your help +! up for me

Comment: how can i do that, im a bit new to titanium, can you show the documentation and i can take it from thier!!

Comment: can you give me an example. i tried the above, i edited the question, thanks

Answer (score 0):

refer to the image object through `this`. when the event handler is triggered, your `likeImage` may not even be defined anymore or can point to another object while the `this` keyword will always point to current object in a function/object. so you should do

```
likeImage.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    this.image = 'unlike.jpg';
});
```

in your code, you declare `var likeImage` in the for scope (not the global one) and you redeclare that variable in each loop's iteration, so your variable `likeImage` is holding a reference only to the last image object created.
For example, after the execution of the loop, the variable `a` will always be equal to 9 :

```
for(var i=0;i<10;i++)
    var a = i;
alert(a);
```

Comment: No worries, I just counteracted the vote down. You highlight a great point about the context of the variables, specifically that inside the event handler, likeImage has certainly changed from what it was originally. However, adding an event listener to each row element isn't very scalable. It's much easier to bind to the container tableView and then deal with the e.row.whatever. I suspect that is why you were voted down. You also could have brought up closures as a protection against variable redefinition across callbacks.